# Python Multiprocessing not honoring LD_LIBRARY_PATH for dynamic loading

Tags: python, matlab, shared-libraries, python-multiprocessing

I am working on a python 3.5 project that uses multiprocessing, the worker process needs to be able to call compiled MATLAB code. In order to not have to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable before running python (it causes conflicts with libexpat), I want to have only this worker process using the altered LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I figured this would work fine since processes created with `fork()` are started with any environment changes made in the parent. I am using

```
matlab_runtime_paths = [
    '/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v91/runtime/glnxa64',
    '/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v91/bin/glnxa64',
    '/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v91/sys/os/glnxa64',
    '/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v91/sys/opengl/lib/glnxa64'
]
system_lib_dir = '{}/lib'.format(sys.prefix)

lib_paths = matlab_runtime_paths + [system_lib_dir]
lib_paths_format = ':'.join(lib_paths)
os.putenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', lib_paths_format)
```

to set the environment variable in parent process, then later in the worker process I have

```
def matlab_worker(matlab_pipe_end):
    import service
    service.initialize_stub()
```

which crashes because it is unable to find the library properly. I can see that the environment variable is being set correct, if I add

```
def matlab_worker(matlab_pipe_end):
    os.system('echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH')
    import service
    service.initialize_stub()
```

the variable is set, I can even do

```
def matlab_worker(matlab_pipe_end):
    os.system('ldd <path>/service.so')
    import service
    service.initialize_stub()
```

and see that all shared objects are resolved, yet python fails to honor this setting, crashing on the import. I'm assuming because the dynamic loader doesnt re-read the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable after a fork (can that be correct? It doesnt sound correct but I cant find any documentation about it)

Is there any way to do what I want or is there something wrong with my code? I should note that this code works fine if the parent process is launched with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...` and that I have made sure there are no conflicting libraries that could be screwing up the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm assuming because the dynamic loader doesnt re-read
>   the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable after a fork

That's true, by the time you call `putenv` dynamic linker has already parsed `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and built it's internal tables for resolving symbols. You won't be able to rebuild those without `exec`.

Alternatively, you can

- at startup, see if paths have been set and if they haven't, set them and re-`exec` the script
- change worker scripts to be standalone so that they can be `exec`-ed rather than `fork`-ed
- start your main app with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set
- manually load needed libraries via `dlopen`, using absolute paths

Comment: Ok and I assume there isnt a way to communicate to the dynamic loader at runtime that it should add another search path?

Comment: @MaxEhrlich Unfortunately there isn't.